# Can't get destination URL of Ad by Adwords API

Tags: php, api, google-ads-api

I want to get the destination URL by using Google Adwords API(v201509).
Cording with PHP.

In the following code, I'm trying to get the url by using 'get' method of AdGroupAdService.
As a result, I could get ad->displayUrl properly but couldn't get ad->url and ad->finalUrls (null given).

What am I doing wrong?

adwords.php with the following code -

```
$adGroupAdService = $user->GetService('AdGroupAdService', ADWORDS_VERSION);
// Create selector.
$selector = new Selector();
$selector->fields = array('Headline', 'Id');
$selector->ordering[] = new OrderBy('Headline', 'ASCENDING');

// Create paging controls.
$selector->paging = new Paging(0, AdWordsConstants::RECOMMENDED_PAGE_SIZE);

do {
    // Make the get request.
    $page = $adGroupAdService->get($selector);

    // Display results.
    if (isset($page->entries)) {
        foreach ($page->entries as $adGroupAd) {
            array_push($googleAccountStructure, $adGroupAd);
            //var_dump($adGroupAd);
        }
    }

    // Advance the paging index.
    $selector->paging->startIndex += AdWordsConstants::RECOMMENDED_PAGE_SIZE;
} while ($page->totalNumEntries > $selector->paging->startIndex);
```

Answer (score 4):

Please update your selector fields with this one

```
$selector->fields = array('Headline', 'Id', 'CreativeFinalUrls', 'Url');
```

As per adwords api doc if you use Upgraded URLs you need to pass Final URLs in selector fields

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201509/AdGroupAdService.Ad#finalUrls

Comment: @KazuhiroKamata If this answer is satisfactory, you should accept it by clicking the check mark.